# simple tensorflow code not work

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am learning Tensorflow, and this is a simple code I wrote today. It doesn't give the expected output, and I am exhausted in figuring out why. Could you give me a hint? Many thanks!!

I just want TF to do a line fitting: **find 'a' and 'b' to fit a line a*(0:99)+b**.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a=0.05
b=18.7
data = a*np.linspace(0,99,num=100)+b+np.random.randn(100)/100
tf.reset_default_graph()

X=tf.constant(np.linspace(0,99,num=100),dtype=tf.float32)
Y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None])
a_hat = tf.get_variable("a_hat", initializer =0.0,dtype=tf.float32)
b_hat = tf.get_variable("b_hat", initializer =0.0,dtype=tf.float32)
Y_hat=  tf.add(tf.multiply(X,a_hat),b_hat)
loss = tf.reduce_mean((Y-Y_hat)**2)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.00001).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(100):
        _ , lossnow = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={Y: data})        
        print(lossnow)
        print(a_hat.eval())
        print(b_hat.eval())
```

In the result, I can see the loss is going down. But finally it gives result

a_hat = 0.33133847 (it should be 0.05)

b_hat = 0.014483764 (it should be 18.7)

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very small learning rate `0.00001` and only 100 training steps it looks like. I suspect it just hasn't converged yet. Try a larger learning rate (perhaps a decaying learning rate if you care that much), and/or more training steps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried a larger rate 0.0001 and saw the loss decrements in the first few iterations (epoch = 0,1,2,3), and then stays almost constant since then (epoch = 4,5,...,99). The final output is still about a_hat=0.33, b_hat=0.01..........

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for this problem is that your learning rate and step are both too small to converge, for me,change `learning rate` to `0.0003` and change `for epoch in range(100)`to `for epoch in range(30000)`,just has the correct answer.
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6iP7.png)

By the way,if you check the loss trend during training,you will find its value is continuously getting small a little,you should just find that the learning rate or step are not proper.

Comment: This helps. I tried 0.0003 and 30000 and I got the same result as you mentioned and this is the expected result. Thanks a lot!